# Will there be any changes in my chat code while shifting from lync server to skype for business

Tags: lync, skype-for-business

We have developed a C# based chat application based on lync server provided by microsoft and this is tested and deployed. Now there is a need for one of our customer to move from lync server to skype for business server.

Please let me know will there be any changes needed in our chatting application, where we have used lync APIs, when we move to skype for business server?

Comment: Would be great to know something more about your application, did it interact with SQL (the tables might have changed) or did you used only UCWA?

Comment: My application code do not interact with SQL directly. Only UCWA is used.

Answer (score 0):

As you said your application is using UCWA the following apply here then (depending which Lync version your customer is using):

- In general Lync Server 2013 CU1 and above used UCWA 1.0.* (Lync 2013 RTM didn´t have UCWA) while Skype for business Server 2015 used UCWA 2.0.*
- In coexistence mode (Lync 2010 and Skype for Business Server 2015) your customer must point the Autodiscover CNAME (Lyncdiscover. and LyncDiscoverinternal.) to a Skype for Business Server 2015 pool in order support custom UCWA 2.0 application development (as written [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-docs/blob/master/Skype/UCWA/RootURL.md)). But that's for Lync 2010 which do not have any UCWA on its frontend server as written [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/270f79b2-12e2-488f-951e-82ead67fcd0e/ucwa-on-lync-2010?forum=ucwebapi).
- A Lync 2013 mobile client used also the UCWA (as mentioned [here](http://www.msxfaq.de/lync/mobile/lync2013mobileios.htm) or [here](http://blog.schertz.name/2013/07/understanding-lync-2013-mobility/)) and is compatible with Skype for Business I assume UCWA 2.0 works also with UCWA 1.0 code.
- The UCWA 1.0 Code samples, Get started, What is this API?, Core features and Reference URLs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162980.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) all points now to the UCWA 2.0 links I assume UCWA 2.0 works also with UCWA 1.0 code.

**Conclusion:**
Without knowing your code its not easy to answer that, but based on the above it might work out of the box if it was working for the latest Lync 2013 version.